# Adding attachments to mule message

Tags: mule, message, attachment

We are kind of stuck and do not know how to send attachments in mule message. We have some code in place that adds outbound attachments, but the values for Content-Disposition and Content-Type are autogenerated by mule and are not matching what is expected on the server. I have pasted the message that we are generating, the message that is expected (note the differences on content-types and content-dispositions).

The content-disposition has to be “inline” on payload and “attachment” on the part of data-file.xml, but instead mule generates Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload" and Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data-file.xml"
This is the code snippet we are using to generate attachments:

ByteArrayDataSource ds = new org.mule.message.ds.ByteArrayDataSource((byte[])docInput.getDataSet(),ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME,"application/pdf");
DataHandler dh = new javax.activation.DataHandler(ds);
msg.addOutboundAttachment(ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, dh);

Generated-Message-By_mule

```
POST /Operations/GenerateDocument HTTP/1.1
X-MULE_ENDPOINT: http://bxl-rs-d1-vm:42420/Operations/GenerateDocument
X-MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE: -1
X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
X-MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID: be11dc40-a0af-11e4-89da-080027001cc8
Client-Authorization: YyoAjWLrpsySg7Euxf9zs3S/ujAPjFuRkT7di6/Dk9o=
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=" WeqbofBr94jK6QxpiWP36xMWse3bxwG21uQZed6”
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 14:22:20 GMT
X-MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE: -1
Accept: application/xml
X-MULE_SESSION: rO0ABXNyACNvcmcubXVsZS5zZXNzaW9uLkRlZmF1bHRNdWxlU2Vzc2lvbi7rdtEW7GGKAwAFWgAFdmFsaWRMAA1mbG93Q29uc3RydWN0dAAmTG9yZy9tdWxlL2FwaS9jb25zdHJ1Y3QvRmxvd0NvbnN0cnVjdDtMAAJpZHQAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO0wACnByb3BlcnRpZXN0AA9MamF2YS91dGlsL01hcDtMAA9zZWN1cml0eUNvbnRleHR0ACdMb3JnL211bGUvYXBpL3NlY3VyaXR5L1NlY3VyaXR5Q29udGV4dDt4cAFwdAAkYmUxMjc4ODAtYTBhZi0xMWU0LTg5ZGEtMDgwMDI3MDAxY2M4c3IAJWphdmEudXRpbC5Db2xsZWN0aW9ucyRTeW5jaHJvbml6ZWRNYXAbc/kJS0s5ewMAAkwAAW1xAH4AA0wABW11dGV4dAASTGphdmEvbGFuZy9PYmplY3Q7eHBzcgAkb3JnLm11bGUudXRpbC5DYXNlSW5zZW5zaXRpdmVIYXNoTWFwndHZ72dFzgADAAB4cHcMP0AAAAAAABAAAAABdAAMT3BlcmF0aW9uVmFydAAQZ2VuZXJhdGVEb2N1bWVudHhxAH4ACXhweA==
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: bxl-rs-d1-vm:42420
Content-Length: 16645

--WeqbofBr94jK6QxpiWP36xMWse3bxwG21uQZed6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns12:GenerateDocumentRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-Push" xmlns:ns3="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-Update" xmlns:ns4="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-PushFeedback" xmlns:ns5="http://www.sodexo.be/schemas/organization-api/1.0" xmlns:ns6="http://www.sodexo.be/schemas/organization-api/Phoenix-Organization-Update" xmlns:ns7="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-UpdateFeedback" xmlns:ns8="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Address-Management" xmlns:ns9="http://net.sxpbelux.eurodb.services/eurodbServiceSchema-addressRequest" xmlns:ns10="http://net.sxpbelux.eurodb.services/eurodbServiceSchema-resultType" xmlns:ns11="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Document-Management" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Compro.Services.Contracts.DataContracts" xmlns:ns13="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:ns14="http://net.sxpbelux.eurodb.services/eurodbServiceSchema-addressSearchRequest" xmlns:ns15="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-Base" xmlns:ns16="http://www.sodexo.be/schemas/organization-api/Phoenix-OrganizationServices-Base" xmlns:ns17="http://www.sodexo.be/schemas/organization-api/Phoenix-Organization-UpdateFeedback" xmlns:ns18="http://net.sxpbelux.eurodb.services/eurodbServiceSchema-searchAddressResultType"><ns12:AttachmentFiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><ns12:BusinessContext>ServiceVoucher</ns12:BusinessContext><ns12:BusinessReference>Work_Voucher_Assigned</ns12:BusinessReference><ns12:CommunicationKey>CommunicationKey</ns12:CommunicationKey><ns12:DataFile>data-file.xml</ns12:DataFile><ns12:FileFormat>DOCX</ns12:FileFormat></ns12:GenerateDocumentRequest>
--WeqbofBr94jK6QxpiWP36xMWse3bxwG21uQZed6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data-file.xml"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:DocumentData xmlns:ns2="http://www.sodexo.com/CRM-Integration-Template">
    <Contacts>
        <Contact>
            <email>email@abc.com</email>
            <firstName>firstName</firstName> ....
```

Message_expected_by_server

```
POST http://besvc-hq1000057:42420/Operations/GenerateDocumentWithAttachment/ HTTP/1.1
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 13:31:24 GMT
Accept: application/xml
X-Compro-Username: ASI
Client-Authorization: S/rumqB+P0jfzY54eSeAGrKeMCfy7RYizno5A8D0ulI=
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d"
Host: besvc-hq1000057:42420
Content-Length: 26128
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
--d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
[... some xml data ...]
--d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order_created_badcom_data.xml
[... some xml content ...]
--d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a.docx
[... some binary content ...]
--d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a2.docx
[... some binary content ...]
--d1261136-19f2-463e-ac7e-e8925c807c7d--
```

If you have any ideas on how to get this to work, kindly let us know.

Thanks and regards,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the Content-Type on the message as follows:

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/pdf" doc:name="Content-Type"/>
```

You can replace the 'application/pdf' with your desired value. The same applies to the other property you want to modify.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that this is mule's limitation - we do not have control over setting content-disposition value when adding attachments using message.addOutboundAttachment() method.

The workarounds for this is to have your own http transport connector implemented or implement your client using any rest client framework or http client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work fine and will set attachment with the message :-

```
<set-attachment value="#[message.payload]" contentType="application/pdf" attachmentName="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" doc:name="Attachment" />
```

Where you can replace `#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]` directly with file name or can keep as same if you are using a file inbound endpoint